# How to deal with an Rcpp::XPtr that may have one of several types

Tags: c++, templates, rcpp, rcpparmadillo

I'm in the situation where I have an `Rcpp::XPtr` to an Armadillo object (e.g. `arma::Mat`, which may be a matrix of one of the supported data types). Now I'd like to write a function that queries the number of elements. The best I could come up with so far is the following (inspired by [bigstatsr](https://github.com/privefl/bigstatsr/blob/272951f4b74c2d41fb442eb8ca2f33fe949d1abc/inst/include/bigstatsr/types.h#L6)):

```cpp
#define DISPATCH_DATA_TYPE(CALL)                               \
{                                                              \
  switch (data_type)                                           \
  {                                                            \
    case 1: CALL(unsigned short)                               \
    case 2: CALL(unsigned int)                                 \
    case 3: CALL(unsigned long)                                \
    case 4: CALL(short)                                        \
    case 5: CALL(int)                                          \
    case 6: CALL(long)                                         \
    case 7: CALL(float)                                        \
    case 8: CALL(double)                                       \
    default: throw Rcpp::exception("Unsupported data type.");  \
  }                                                            \
}

template <typename T>
arma::uword mat_length(SEXP mat)
{
  Rcpp::XPtr< arma::Mat<T> > p(mat);
  return p->n_elem;
}

#define MAT_LENGTH(TYPE) return mat_length<TYPE>(mat);

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::uword mat_length(SEXP mat, int data_type)
{
  DISPATCH_DATA_TYPE(MAT_LENGTH)
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this? I'm using this pattern for quite a few functions and the verbosity is becoming a problem. Ideally I'd have a single but concise function, like (doesn't work of course)

```cpp
arma::uword mat_length(SEXP mat)
{
  Rcpp::XPtr<arma::Mat> p(mat);
  return p->n_elem;
}
```

instead of two functions + a macro for every single instance where I pass an `XPtr` like that from R to C.

Bonus question: is there anything obviously wrong with the macro-based approach? Is this somehow inefficient or could lead to problems down the line?

To create a reproducible example, add

```cpp
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP setup_mat(arma::uword n_rows, arma::uword n_cols)
{
  arma::mat* res = new arma::mat(n_rows, n_cols);
  return Rcpp::XPtr<arma::mat>(res);
}
```

and run `Rcpp::sourceCpp()` on the file in R.

Comment: First thing I have to say is that the use of a macro `#define DISPATCH_DATA_TYPE(CALL) {` looks horrible - why would you do that rather than a proper (possibly `constexpr`) function? Second; `case 1: CALL(unsigned short)                               \
    case 2: CALL(unsigned int)                                 \
    case 3: CALL(unsigned long)` etc, are these all really supposed to fall through to the next `case`? That just looks wrong - I would have expected some `break` statements in there..

Comment: @JesperJuhl thanks for taking an interest in my question. I see you don't like the macro approach. As to why I'm doing this, I'm afraid I don't have a good answer: I saw this somewhere and thought it'd solve my problem in a reasonable way. Is it more of an aesthetic distaste, or is there something objectively bad about this? If you think this should be done differently, would you be so kind and sketch an alternative solution? Are the missing `break`s a problem? The `CALL`s contain `return` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best non-macro approach I could come up with so far (using `boost::mp11`) is the following:

Key parts:

- a type list (`mp11::mp_list`, called `types`) defining my set of types
- helper metafunctions `num_type_from_i` and `i_form_num_type` to query type given an index/index given a type
- a templated struct `dispatch_impl`, used recursively, providing iteration over the type list
- a specialized version of `dispatch_impl` for terminating the recursion
- a convenience function `dispatch_type()` calling `dispatch_impl` and defining the list length/max recursion depth
- example function objects `MatInit` and `Length` alongside their R interfaces `mat_init()` and `length()`

```cpp
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]

#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

#include <boost/mp11/list.hpp>
#include <boost/mp11/algorithm.hpp>

namespace mp11 = boost::mp11;

using types = mp11::mp_list<int, float, double>;

template <std::size_t I>
using num_type_from_i = mp11::mp_at_c<types, I>;

template <typename T>
using i_form_num_type = mp11::mp_find<types, T>;

template <typename T, std::size_t N> struct dispatch_impl
{
  template <std::size_t K, template<typename> class Fn, typename ...Ar>
  static auto call(std::size_t i, Ar&&... rg) ->
      decltype(Fn<mp11::mp_at_c<T, 0>>()(std::forward<Ar>(rg)...))
  {
    if (i == 0)
    {
      return Fn<mp11::mp_at_c<T, K>>()(std::forward<Ar>(rg)...);
    } 
    else
    {
      return dispatch_impl<T, N - 1>::template call<K + 1, Fn>(i - 1,
          std::forward<Ar>(rg)...);
    }
  }
};

template <typename T> struct dispatch_impl<T, 1>
{
  template <std::size_t K, template<typename> class Fn, typename ...Ar>
  static auto call(std::size_t i, Ar&&... rg) ->
      decltype(Fn<mp11::mp_at_c<T, 0>>()(std::forward<Ar>(rg)...))
  {
    if (i == 0)
    {
      return Fn<mp11::mp_at_c<T, K>>()(std::forward<Ar>(rg)...);
    }
    else
    {
      throw std::runtime_error("Unsupported data type.");
    }
  }
};

template <template<typename> class Fn, typename ...Ar>
auto dispatch_type(std::size_t type, Ar&&... rg) ->
    decltype(Fn<num_type_from_i<0>>()(std::forward<Ar>(rg)...))
{
  using n_types = mp11::mp_size<types>;
  return dispatch_impl<types, std::size_t{n_types::value}>::template call<0,
      Fn>(type, std::forward<Ar>(rg)...);
}

template <typename T>
struct MatInit
{
  SEXP operator()(arma::uword n_rows, arma::uword n_cols)
  {
    auto res = new arma::Mat<T>(n_rows, n_cols);
    auto ind = std::size_t{i_form_num_type<T>::value};
    return Rcpp::XPtr<arma::Mat<T>>(res, true, Rcpp::wrap(ind));
  }
};

// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP mat_init(arma::uword n_rows, arma::uword n_cols, std::size_t data_type)
{
  return dispatch_type<MatInit>(data_type, n_rows, n_cols);
}

template <typename T>
struct Length
{
  arma::uword operator()(SEXP x)
  {
    return Rcpp::XPtr<arma::Mat<T>>(x)->n_elem;
  }
};

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::uword length(SEXP x)
{
  std::size_t type = Rcpp::as<std::size_t>(R_ExternalPtrTag(x));
  return dispatch_type<Length>(type, x);
}
```

This way the list of types can easily be modified and apart from requiring templated function objects instead of function templates, implementation of functions such as `length()` is fairly succinct.

Furthermore, I don't have to pass the data type index between R and C, but can store the index within the external pointer structure.

If anyone sees potential issues, I'd be keen on hearing from them.